# Built in prime checking function

Tags: c++

Does C++ have any built in function to check if the number is prime or not. If yes, then in which library?

Below is my implementation. But was just looking if there is any built in function. Searching on Google just gives user based implementations.

```
int isprime(int N){
    if(N<2 || (!(N&1) && N!=2))
        return 0;
    for(int i=3; i*i<=N; i+=2){
        if(!(N%i))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Nicks written in all caps hurt my eyes if they are that long.

Comment: If C++ included functions for everything like this, it would be very clunky. That's what C++ has going for it. How often do you actually need to find prime numbers?

Comment: @chris: RTTI and locale handling are clunky already :(

Comment: @MatthieuM., My point was, look at C++ vs. Java. Look how much Java has that C++ doesn't for every aspect of the language.

Comment: @chris: Yes I understand. Actually, C++ is not lightweight by design, and the Standard library part is extending and *will keep extending*. We already got the thread + timing utilities, and there is reflexion about a filesystem abstraction layer for the next version. It is not that the committee wants to keep the library lean (not as much as they want to keep the core language lean), but more a problem of designing interfaces that fit many different OSes.

Comment: @chris yep, not including xml parser or usable parallel collections really makes c++ a much better language ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: no, there's no such function.

The only time the word "prime" is used in the standard is a footnote in 26.5.3.2, which is where the `mersenne_twister_engine` class template is described. The footnote says:

> 274) The name of this engine refers, in part, to a property of its period: For properly-selected values of the parameters, the period is closely related to a large Mersenne prime number.

If such function existed, the standard would contain more occurrences of that word, as it would use it to describe the behavior of that function.

Answer (score 8):

No, there's no built-in function that checks for prime.

The solution you posted could be improved on: the `i*i` can be avoided if you only calculate the square root of `N` once.

If you know the range of the number you want to check, you can use a sieve and a map, as to not calculate repeatedly - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Depending on the magnitude of `N`, a few integer multiplies are surely faster than (1) conversion to floating-point, (2) square root, and (3) conversion back to integer.  If addition is faster on a particular architecture, one can also easily avoid the multiply by using the fact that the difference between successive squares is `square(i+1) = square(i) + 2*i+1`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no C++ "build-in" function, but you can resolve this with compile time efficiency using metaprogramming.

```
template <int i>
struct D
{
    D(void *);
    operator int();
};

template <int p, int i>
struct is_prime
{
    enum { prim = (p%i) && is_prime<(i>2?p:0), i>::prim };
};

template <int i>
struct Prime_print
{
    Prime_print<i-1>    a;
    enum { prim = is_prime<i,i-1>::prim };
    void f() { D<i> d = prim; }
};

struct is_prime<0,0> { enum { prim = 1 }; };
struct is_prime<0,1> { enum { prim = 1 }; };
struct Prime_print<2>
{
    enum { prim = 1 };
    void f() { D<2> d = prim; }
};

void foo()
{
    Prime_print<10> a;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The widely available GMP library has a fast function for probabilistic prime testing, see https://gmplib.org/manual/Number-Theoretic-Functions.html

Just convert your integer, example code:

```
bool is_prob_prime(long l)
{
    mpz_t bigint;
    mpz_init_set_si(bigint, l);
    bool ret = mpz_probab_prime_p(bigint, 25) > 0;
    mpz_clear(bigint);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template <size_t upper_limit> class prime_table final {
public:
  static_assert(upper_limit >= 2, "upper_limit too tiny");
  prime_table() {
    table_.set();
    table_.reset(0);
    table_.reset(1);

    size_t root = size_t(std::sqrt(upper_limit)) + 1;
    for (size_t pos = 2; pos <= root; ++pos) {
      for (size_t multiplier = 2; pos * multiplier <= upper_limit;
           ++multiplier) {
        table_.reset(pos * multiplier);
      }
    }
  }

  inline bool is_prime(size_t value) { return table_.test(value); }

protected:
  std::bitset<upper_limit + 1> table_;
};
```

It generates a prime number table then you can use is_prime() to test against a number in range [0, upper_limit]