# program that reads an integer, and prints all the perfect numbers

Tags: c++

```
int n;
int sum;
    
cout << "write a number";
cin >> n;

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    sum = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if (i % j == 0)
            sum = sum + j;
    }
    if (sum == i)
        cout << i<< endl;
}
```

Why do I always get 1 as a result? I couldn't understand the logic of it. When I change the second `for` loop and make it `i/2`, I get the correct result, but I couldn't understand how it worked.

input 1000
expected result = 6 28 496

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the program with a debugger to see what it does at each step?

Comment: Have you considered implementing this through [Euler's algorithm](https://www.cuemath.com/numbers/perfect-numbers/) using `<cmath>`? According to it -- for `n`, if `2^n - 1` is a prime number then `(2^n -1) x (2^(n-1))` is a perfect number! This might burn less CPU cycle. You already have `std::pow()` and use any good algorithm to find [`is_prime(n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896915/built-in-prime-checking-function) available online.

Comment: ```i``` should not be included for the inner loop because by its definition, perfect number excludes itself when considering divisors. ```i/2``` results in a correct answer because a number's divisors excluding itself are no greater than half of itself. Simple proof:  If i < 4, it has only itself and 1 as divisors. If i >= 4, i/2 * i/2 = i^2/4 >= i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remind about mathematics. Refer to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number)

> In number theory, a perfect number is a positive integer that is equal
> to the sum of its positive divisors, excluding the number itself.

So, in your code, you are making sum of ALL divisors of i include itself. That's why you only get result `1`.

You should change it simply.

```
for (int j = 1; j < i; j++)
```

Comment: Good answer. But a maximum divisor for any number will be at half. Hence for the optimization purpose, it's logical to loop only through the half viz. `j <= i/2`. Remaining half will simply burn CPU cycle for no good reason.

Comment: @iammilind Good point. But I just focus OP than optimize algorithm. Thanks.

Comment: The OP has a mention of `i/2`, which works fine. Apparently the user already has the code written and mostly they are experimenting with it to understand it.